# Access spring batch job parameters in a decider

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job where I put a file name as a job parameter , and I need to use this parameter in a decider  how can I do that please.

my decider :

```java
public class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider
{     
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution,
              org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution stepExecution)
    {
        String fileName=jobExecution.getExecutionContext().getString("file");
        System.out.println(" filae name from step execution : "+fileName);
        FileRead fileRead=new FileRead();
        if (fileName.equals("aaaa"))
    {
            return FlowExecutionStatus.COMPLETED;
        }
    else 
        {
            return FlowExecutionStatus.FAILED;
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: What is decider ?

Comment: I added the decider . it is to make  adecision in a job based on something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JobExecutionDecider#decide` method takes a parameter of type `JobExecution` which allows you to get job parameters using `JobExecution.getJobParameters`. Here is a quick example:

```
class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {

    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();
        // get the job parameter from jobParameters
        return null; // return the FlowExecutionStatus as needed
    }
}
```